# Number of Zeroes Inside Unit Circle

Tags: polynomials, roots, circles

Let $a, b, d$ be real numbers and $c$ a complex number and define the quartic polynomial
$$
z^4+z^3 (a+ i b)+z^2c+z (d-ib)+1
$$
I want to know sufficient and necessary conditions for when three of the roots are strictly inside the unit circle $|z| < 1$. By the fundamental theorem of algebra, the product of the roots is one, so there are at most three solutions strictly inside the unit circle. I'd also be happy if I could determine when there are three . Of course there exists an exact formula for determining the roots of a quartic polynomial, but it is extremely messy and doesn't give you the norm of the rooms.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try to use [Rouchè Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem) in the unitary circle...

Answer (score 1):

Let $A = a+ib$ and $B = d-ib$.
Given any $a,b,d$, the closed parametric curve
$$ \gamma(t) = - e^{2it} -A e^{it} - B e^{-it} - e^{-2it}, \ 0 \le t \le 2 \pi $$
gives those $c$ for which there is a root on the unit circle.  For $c$ outside the curve, by Rouché there are as many roots inside the unit circle as for $z^2$, namely two.  As you cross the curve (at a regular point), the number either increases or decreases by $1$.   If there are any $c$ that make the number $3$, they will form one or more of the regions into which the curve divides the complex plane.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Just a quick question, if $c$ is outside the curve, how can Rouché's theorem be applied? Thanks!

Comment: Rouché applies when $|c|$ is sufficiently large, as the term $c z^2$ dominates the others.  And then  the number of roots inside the circle stays constant in the unbounded component of the complement of the curve.

Comment: Thanks! Can I also use Rouché to argue that if my polynomial has three roots in the unit circle, then $|A|>|B|$? Because then the polynomial $z^3 A+z B$ has three roots inside the unit circle. Thus my sufficient and necessary conditions are that $c$ is inside the parametric curve you give and $|A|>|B|$?

Comment: No, Rouché gives a sufficient condition, not a necessary one.

Comment: Could I not use the symmetric version of  [Rouché](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem#Symmetric_version) if $c$ is not large enough? Because based on my numerical trials in Mathematica, these are necessary and sufficient.

Comment: It might be the case here (where $\text{Im}(B) = - \text{Im}(A)$), but I don't see how it could come just from Rouché.

Comment: I think you're right, it doesn't come from Rouché, but I still think it's true. Suppose we have three roots less than one $z_1, z_2, z_3$.  Then from Vieta's formula, the product of the roots is 1 and furthermore $|A| = |z_1+z_2+z_3+(z_1z_2z_3)^{-1}|$ and $|B| = |z_1^{-1}+z_2^{-1}+z_3^{-1}+z_1 z_2 z_3|$. Now I just need to show that $|z_1+z_2+z_3+(z_1z_2z_3)^{-1}| >|z_1^{-1}+z_2^{-1}+z_3^{-1}+z_1 z_2 z_3| $ for any $z_{1}, z_{2}, z_{3}$ with norm smaller than one. Not quite sure how to do that though.